# GeoServer style based on number points returned

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, heat-map, dynamic

I have a point layer with many points. I am filtering these points from the frontend application (OpenLayers+Angular) with multiple filtering options (dropdowns, checkboxes, etc.) using CQL_FILTER parameter in the WMS URL call. So with all the combinations from all the UI filters, every time I get a different number of points as a result, varying from several points to almost a million points.

If the result is many points, maybe above certain threshold, I want to display a heatmap. If the result is only several points, below the threshold, I want to display individual points.
I have the SLDs for both heatmap and individual points defined.

But how can I do this dynamic style selection based on number of points returned by the WMS with filters applied?

Answer (score 1):

The style itself generally does not handle the result "as a whole" but "one record at a time" instead, so there is no out-of-the-box solution to your problem in SLD.

Possible alternative is to drive from the client side:

- Make a WFS query with the same filter, but with resultType set to hits, e.g:

https://gs-main.geosolutionsgroup.com/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp%3Astates&resultType=hits

- Based on the results, switch the "&styles" parameter in your WMS request between a point style and a heatmap style.